# Query database in Django

Tags: python, django

My first problem is I want to get the inserted latest id in auth_user on Django but currently it showing the name of the row database. I use the example below. The result should be Id value not the name. Please help me

```
 obj = User.objects.latest('id')
```

> The second problem is I want to insert in auth_user_user_permission table like this. The problem is how to convert this into django format.

```
lastestid = User.objects.latest('id')
insert into auth_user_user_permission where user_id=latestid and permission_id =(Select auth_permission Where name="sample" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = User.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.